# Get all days and date for a given month

Tags: php, arrays, date

Would like to retrieve all days and date for a given month. Have this currently which shows all the days for the current month, but how do I parse in a specified month instead?

```
$list=array();
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{
    $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, date('m'), $d, date('Y'));
    if (date('m', $time)==date('m'))
        $list[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $time);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: specified month of which year?

Comment: Sorry, specific year as well. eg. 201403

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try this

```
$list=array();
$month = 12;
$year = 2014;

for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{
    $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
    if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
        $list[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $time);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: in this there is a issue when trying to get all dates for February Month (29 dates). So First get how many days are in month by $dcount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year); and then loop for that dates count only for($d=1; $d<=$dcount; $d++)

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
$month = "05";
$year = "2014";

$start_date = "01-".$month."-".$year;
$start_time = strtotime($start_date);

$end_time = strtotime("+1 month", $start_time);

for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
{
   $list[] = date('Y-m-d-D', $i);
}

print_r($list);
```

See [**Demo**](http://codepad.org/vzPkIFsK)

Comment: This solution fails beacuse of Daylight Saving Time. For example: if you output October 2019, 27th of October is in array twice because the time changed for one hour. So just add an if (date already in array) before pushing in array.

Answer (score 6):

```
$days = cal_days_in_month( 0, $month, $year);
```

cal_days_in_month: Return the number of days in a month for a given year and calendar.
First parameter is "calendar":

0 or CAL_GREGORIAN - Gregorian Calendar
1 or CAL_JULIAN - Julian Calendar
2 or CAL_JEWISH - Jewish Calendar
3 or CAL_FRENCH - French Revolutionary Calendar

http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-info.php

Answer (score 3):

for object oriented users,

```
function getDaysInYearMonth (int $year, int $month, string $format){
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-n", "$year-$month");

    $datesArray = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$date->format("t"); $i++){
        $datesArray[] = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-n-d", "$year-$month-$i")->format($format);
    }

 return $datesArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned PHP's built-in, no extra extensions `DateTime` class.

```
<?php
$daysInAugust2020 = (new DateTime("20200801"))->format('t');
print_r($daysInAugust2020);
```

You'll have to append some day to your `YYYYMM` string, but it's not that hard: every month has a 1st. So you can always add `01`.

The trick here is the `t` format, which just returns the number of days in the month the date is in. If you're trying to get this month's amount of days, it's even easier. Just running the `date()` function creates a DateTime set to right now, so the above code becomes:

```
<?php
$daysInAugust2020 = date('t');
print_r($daysInAugust2020);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

```
$y_m = '2018-10'; // set year and month.

$list = array();
$d = date('d', strtotime('last day of this month', strtotime($y_m))); // get max date of current month: 28, 29, 30 or 31.

for ($i = 1; $i <= $d; $i++) {
    $list[] = $y_m . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list=array();
$d = 13;
$year = 2019;

for($m=1; $m<=12; $m++)
{
    $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $m, $d, $year);          
    if (date('m', $time)==$m)       
        $list[]=date('D-d-m-Y', $time);
    }
```

In this one you can put a spesific number and outpout all the days in the year that have the same number. example i wanted to outpout all the 13th days of the month. (if you want to find every Friday 13th that what you have to use)

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm.
Tried **cal_days_in_month** but didn't work.

```
function Get_Month_Dates($year,$month)
{
    $no_of_days = date("t",strtotime($year.'-'.$month));
// date("t") gets the last day of the month 28,29,30,31 (whichever applicable)
    
    $dates = array();
Now we iterate
    
    for($d=1;$d<=$no_of_days;$d++)
    {
//If you want to add leading zeroes to all the dates
        $day = (strlen($d)==1) ? '0'.$d : $d; 

        $month = (strlen($month)==1) ? '0'.$month : $month; // To add leading zero to the month
        
        $dates[] = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
$c_year = date("Y");
$c_month = date("m");
$no_day = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $c_month, $c_year);           
for($i=1; $i<=$no_day; $i++){ 
     $cd[] .= $c_year.'-'.$c_month.'-'.$i;
}
$date_val = json_encode($cd) 
print_r($date_val); // date array
```

Comment: It is better if you also explain what the code is doing for others' understanding.

Answer (score -1):

This will get all date current month

```
$alldatethismonth = range(1, $month);
foreach($alldatethismonth as $date){
    echo date("Y-m-").$date."<br>";
}
```

And this will get all date for given month

```
$month = date("t", strtotime('2021-09-18'));
$alldatethismonth = range(1, $month);
foreach($alldatethismonth as $date){
    echo date("Y-m-").$date."<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, for example Feb has 28 days, your code returns until the 30th.

Answer (score -3):

you may use `$list[]=date('Y-M-D', $time);`

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Some explanation would be great