# PHP for loop to print dates of Month in Codigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a view in codeigniter project to be printed some details including dates of a month. The date range goes from min date to max date abstract from the data in a table, like '2020-01-01' to '2020-08-31'. If a latest date in the table is '2020-10-30', that would be the max date. Suppose that is need to be printed dates for the month of August as '2020-08-01' to '2020-08-31' and include in the view. I used the following code

```
    <?php
        if(!empty($printFuelUse)){
                foreach ($printFuelUse as $rows){               

        $begin = new DateTime($rows->mindate);
        $end = new DateTime($rows->maxdate);              

        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
        $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
               }
        }
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
        echo $dt->format("l Y-m-d H:i:s\n");
        }
    
    ?>
```

$printFuelUse includes array values from model. It is correctly outs mindate & maxdate in the table

I want to get the output as follows :

```
+------------+
|    Date    |
+------------+
| 2020-08-01 |
| 2020-08-02 |
| 2020-08-03 |
| 2020-08-04 |
| 2020-08-05 |
| 2020-08-06 |
| …………       |
| ………….      |
| 2020-08-30 |
| 2020-08-31 |
+------------+
```

But didn't get the expected output. Can anyone help ? Pls. consider only the 1st column of the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all days and date for a given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780293/get-all-days-and-date-for-a-given-month)

Comment: @MCIT Trends but now what output you are getting?

Comment: @  KUMAR. Now printed as 'Saturday 2020-08-01 00:00:00' ............so on

Comment: That corresponds to `"l Y-m-d H:i:s\n"`. If you want a different format, set a different format string.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how date periods help here:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2020-08-01');
$end = new DateTime('2020-08-31');
for ($dt = clone $begin; $dt <= $end; $dt->modify('+1 day')) {
    echo $dt->format("Y-m-d\n");
}
```

Comment: @ Álvaro González. That is edit. Pls see on my edit

Comment: Sorry but your question is mutating in such a way that it's hard to give a definitive answer. `'2020-08-01'` can be a string literal or come from a variable—it doesn't make any difference. If you think it does, please provide the actual values.